# Flask socketIO emit series of events

Tags: reactjs, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I would like server to emit series of events to client (React) after connection is established, Ive tried:

```
@socketio.on('connect')
def test_connect():
    for i in range(10):
        emit('my response', {'data': 'Connected ' + str(i)})
        time_module.sleep(2)
```

but events shows in web browser console at the same time, like they arrived at the same moment, in react I use :

```
useEffect(() => {
    const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);

    socket.on('my response', function (data) {
      console.log('my response: ', data.data);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two potential problems in your server code.

First of all, what is `time_module` in your example? I suspect that is a blocking sleep that you are doing. Instead, I suggest you sleep properly with `socketio.sleep(2)`.

The second problem is that you are doing this in the `connect` event handler. The Socket.IO server waits until you return from the connect handler to decide if the client is accepted or rejected, so in general you do not want this handler to take a long time to run, because the connection isn't fully established until you return. I suggest you move this logic to a background function instead.

The following code addresses both issues:

```py
def initial_events():
    for i in range(10):
        emit('my response', {'data': 'Connected ' + str(i)})
        socketio.sleep(2)

@socketio.on('connect')
def test_connect():
    socketio.start_background_task(initial_events)
```

Comment: This answer is really good, true source of knowledge, time_module was just time module, are there tutorials where I can learn stuff like start_background_task?